# Output values from list of keys with SQLAlchemy, Jinja2, and Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

part of the html:

```
{% for device in casperdevices %}
        <tr>
        {% for key in casperkeys %}
            <td>
                {{ _('%(key)s', key=device[key]) }}
            </td>
            {% if key == 'Report URL' %}
            <td>
                <p><a href="{{ _('%(key)s', key=device[key]) }}">
                    {{ _('%(key)s', key=device[key]) }}</a><p>
            </td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Model:

```
class Casperinv(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    serial = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    display_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    wifimac = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True)
    ip = db.Column(db.String(16), index=True)
    osvers = db.Column(db.String(16), index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), index=True)
```

Keys= `casperkeys = ['serial', 'ip', 'username']`

casperdevices = `Casperinv.query.all()`

The page formats a column/cell as expected in the resulting page that loads, but I can't get it to actually show the output in each cell. Basically I'm trying to get a report to show in the webpage of only the columns that are selected for the logged in user's settings.

When I attempt to use variables in flask shell, it says the SQL alchemy object isn't subscriptable. I'm sure i'm missing something simple syntactically.. typing `casperdevices[0].ip` as an example will show an output.. but how do I get the keys to randomly output in that format to get the output i need?

*Edit* - I should mention that I originally tried using `key=device.key` above as well, with no luck.

*Edit 2* - I think i'm close.. if I run a loop of:

```
for x in casperdevices:
    for y in casperkeys:
        print(vars(x)[y])
```

I get it to print everything I'd be looking for in the flask shell! However when I try to put `key=vars(device)[key]` in the template, it just says that vars is not defined.. cant do a `{% set x = vars(device) %} either, as that triggers the same error. :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cheated.. there's probably a better way to do this w/o changing the format.. but until someone can clue me in on that, here's a solution:
Template:

```
    {% for device in casperdevices.keys() %}
        <tr>
        {% for key in casperkeys %}
            {% if key == 'reporturl' %}
            <td>
                <p><a href="{{ _('%(key)s', key=casperdevices[device][key]) }}">
                    {{ _('%(key)s', key=casperdevices[device][key]) }}</a><p>
            </td>
            {% else %}
            <td>
                {{ _('%(key)s', key=casperdevices[device][key]) }}
            </td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
```

Routes:

```
@bp.route('/reports/casperinv')
@login_required
def casperinv():
    getset = Setting.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).first()
    casperquery = Casperinv.query.all()
    total = len(casperquery)
    casperkeys = json.loads(getset.casper)
    casperdevices = {}
    for x in casperquery:
        casperdevices[x.serial] = vars(x)
    return render_template('/reports/casperinv.html', title=_('Casper Inventory'),
                casperdevices=casperdevices, total=total, casperkeys=casperkeys)
```